# No matching distribution found for tensorflow on Linux running 64bit python 3.4

Tags: python, tensorflow, pip

I am trying to install tensorflow for python3 using pip, and I am getting this error:

`Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for tensorflow`

I know that using 32bit python is commonly the issue, but I am running 64bit Python 3.4.3 on Linux, and pip is version 9.0.1:
`pip 9.0.1 from /home/cjoseph/.local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)`

These versions of pip and python are supposed to be compatible with the tensorflow install 
If I do a verbose install, pip goes through basically all the installation options and decides that none of them are compatible:

`Skipping link https://pypi.python.org/packages/60/36/2d73d4da24cbd3a4913a4fdec8111e02af332975a8dc1c83557b5c47aa09/tensorflow-1.4.0rc0-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=fe56aa114db56265d92b7cbd544c16af (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/tensorflow/); it is not compatible with this Python`

However, I don't understand why the x86_64 python 3.4 "manylinux" wheel is discarded as incompatible. My system meets all those requirements. If I try and install the wheel directly like so, I still get the same 'not compatible' error:

`pip3 install https://pypi.python.org/packages/05/f7/ccf4f218f448c1194df0d52743691bcd835e0fb665a3b7876d929f5218d4/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl#md5=ae3b5d6f98dbf89641b5efbb1864ffe5`

`tensorflow-1.4.0-cp34-cp34m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

I also tried with a link to the tensorflow-hosted binary, same result:

`pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-1.4.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl`

`tensorflow-1.4.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

As a final sanity check tried "python3 -m pip install ..." and the outcome is the same.

I am pretty stumped at this point.

Comment: Gentoo. I was able to install tensorflow fine for python2 on the same system, but I need python 3.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why pip wouldn't work? That is the recommended way to install most python packages on Gentoo.

Anyway, the USE flags: 3.4.3-r1(3.4)(01:55:05 PM 08/17/2016)(gdbm ipv6 ncurses readline sqlite ssl threads xml -build -elibc_uclibc -examples -hardened -tk -wininst)

Comment: I see, thank you. Do you know of a way to find out what exactly pip thinks is wrong/missing? Even with the verbose output, it just says "not compatible" instead of detailing what is missing. Pip3 installation worked perfectly well for a number of other complicated packages (numpy, opencv), but I suppose maybe those depend a different subset of packages.

Comment: ('cp34', 'cp34', 'manylinux1_x86_64')
('cp34', 'cp34', 'linux_x86_64')
('cp34', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64')
('cp34', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64')
('cp34', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64')
('cp34', 'none', 'linux_x86_64')
('cp33', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64')
('cp33', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64')
('cp32', 'abi3', 'manylinux1_x86_64')
('cp32', 'abi3', 'linux_x86_64')
('py3', 'none', 'manylinux1_x86_64')
('py3', 'none', 'linux_x86_64')
('cp34', 'none', 'any')
('cp3', 'none', 'any')
('py34', 'none', 'any')
('py3', 'none', 'any')
('py33', 'none', 'any')...
('py30', 'none', 'any')

Comment: And there you have it - your abi is missing the `m` letter (`cp34` instead of `cp34m` which means your python installation was compiled without `pymalloc`. `tensorflow` offers only wheels that require `pymalloc` to be present (all the `manylinux1` wheels have the `m` letter in the soabi string). This is strange as Gentoo compiles python with `pymalloc` and this can't be changed without an explicit ebuild patching. I guess something is wrong with your python installation. Check that your `pip` belongs to python installed by Gentoo and not some custom python build.

Comment: It's the normal gentoo pip installed

`Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] dev-python/pip-9.0.1-r1::gentoo  PYTHON_TARGETS="python2_7 python3_4 (-pypy) -python3_5 (-python3_6)" 0 KiB`. I reinstalled to make sure, and it replaced the symlinks. I also checked `which pip3` to be sure. I'll try updating python itself.

Comment: Rebuilding python did it